# Can't execute compiled C++ exe file

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin

I am having trouble executing my C++ code. I have written a basic "Hello World" program, and compiled it using the g++ `make` command. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main() {
  cout << "Hello World" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I am on Windows 10, using Emacs for code editing, and CygWin for compilation. I saved this file as hello.cpp. I then navigated to the directory in CygWin. Then I did the command `make hello`. This created hello.exe. Then, I attempted to execute the file using `./hello.exe`. I also tried `./hello` which also didn't work. When I type one of these commands and hit Enter, it just on the next line, not doing anything. I can type in this blank line, but it won't do anything. Does anyone know a way to make my code execute properly. Thank you.

EDIT: I tried running this at cpp.sh, an online C++ compiler, and it worked fine.

Comment: What is the output when the program is ran under windows command prompt (cmd.exe)?

Comment: @NoOrdinaryLove The same as with CygWin.

Comment: Try redirecting the output to a file. hello.exe > log.txt

Comment: @NoOrdinaryLove Same result in terminal, of couse, log.txt is empty.

Comment: what command did you use on the cygwin terminal?

Comment: ./hello.exe. I also tried ./hello, to no avail

Comment: It's probably related to windows 10 blocking your program from running.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling the program? Usually I see people use `gcc hello.cpp`. If you are using make, all I know is to create a make file. Have you created a make file at all? Refer to this [GCC and Make document](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html#zz-2.)

Answer (score 2):

Your program probably is working but the console window is closing before you can see anything.

Try adding an input at the end of the program so it will wait.

I.E.

```
int a;
cin >> a;
```

Comment: The console window doesn't close. It stays open, but eventually I have to close it because it doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is most likely executing, but not outputting anything. That's because it's failing. Try checking the return value after it has run with `echo $?`. If it's not `0` then it has crashed. Also run it in `gdb` and see if it fails. The reason why it's failing is most likely a windows/cygwin clash - it's not your code.

Comment: I ran `echo $?` to check the return value and it said `0`, however, every time I run the program I have to restart CygWin, so the value may not be accurate. I do not know how to run it in `gdb`, although I do have it installed.

Comment: Every time you restart the shell, you lose your old value of `$?`. And it sounds like even the shell is crashing when you run your program.